# What is best practice for fluid designs - using css sprites or inline images?

Tags: css, responsive-design, sprite, css-sprites, fluid-layout

I am working on a web site which is supposed to have a fluid layout. I am currently presented with a dilemma: shall I use css sprite or opt for inline images?

All images will need to be fluid and reduce/enlarge their size on each respective screen size.  I was thinking to use CSS sprite image but that would mean that I need to identify all major screen widths and then slice all images with those respective widths and add them to my sprite...

My questions is: what is the best approach for rendering images in fluid / responsive designs? Sprites, inline images or combination of both?

Thank you!

Comment: Questions regarding "what is the best approach" will generate opinion-based answers and so are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: True, but best practices are based on expert opinions on the subject. So my questions is about what the best practice is 'sprite vs inline images in relation to fluid designs'. I believe that given the fact that there are a lot of experts on this forum I could build my image strategy based on the general mass approach in the front-end community.  If you don't believe that there is an option for best practice I am happy to close the question. I believe it is still relevant to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I think sprites are a little unnecessary, the internet is fast enough now to just use separate bg images. Displaying the correct image by using media queries and constraining the size in fluid designs by using background-size: cover; or contain.

Comment: This is what I have done too... I was debating with myself whether there was a better way. Thanks a lot for your answer Aaron.